# What's wrong with this .htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect (only) mysite/02B /030 etc to theirsite/02B etc.

What's wrong with this? I have the sense that I'm missing something stupidly obvious. :-/

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^0(2B|2Y|2C|2Z|2-|30|33)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://theirsite/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading slash `/` is included in the **REQUEST_URI** variable, so you have to include it also in the regular expression to match the variable.

You may try this complete rule-set instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/0(2B|2Y|2C|2Z|2-|30|33)  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://theirsite/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Do `/02B`, `/02Y`, etc., directories exist in `mysite`? If so, try removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` from the rule-set. That should solve the problem, in case it is not redirecting.

Comment: They don't exist on mysite, only theirsite. Having the !-f / !-d conditions doesn't make a difference (and shouldn't; they're additive). The URLs just 404.

Comment: Tested the rules and found another error. It is "stupidly obvious" as you say but I also made it when copy+pasted your rules. This `RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI)` is WRONG. It should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Argh! That was it. Thanks!